# I need a select box with checkboxes for each item. Any recommendations on a jquery-ui plugin?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I need a html 'control' similar to "CheckedListBox" from WinForms:

```
<select> <optgroup> <option>Item 1</option></optgroup></select>
```

where each item (and group) has a check box which can be individually checked/unchecked with callbacks.

Has anyone found a jquery-ui or other option for accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that with a standard select box, but if you make it into a custom select box and then add in your `input` checkboxes to the items, you could probably achieve what you desire. Do some searches for a jquery custom select box to find what suits you. Here a just a couple I found (untested, and thus not necessarily recommending...)

http://www.mypocket-technologies.com/jquery/SelectBoxPlugin/

http://dervish.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/