# Customized select box

Tags: jsp

Custom tag to write Select box,Each option should have corresponding checkbox.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy: [I need a select box with checkboxes for each item. Any recommendations on a jquery-ui plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256174/i-need-a-select-box-with-checkboxes-for-each-item-any-recommendations-on-a-jquer)