# How to change multi select option to Dropdown Checklist

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have one multi select options like.

```
<div class="Selectoptions">
    <form>
        <select id="selet-please">
            <option>1.Parking</option>
            <option>2.Water</option>
            <option>3.School</option>
            <option>4.Garden</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

It actully multi select. But I need with check box inside select list. using Jquery or java script.

Comment: http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256174/i-need-a-select-box-with-checkboxes-for-each-item-any-recommendations-on-a-jque

Comment: why dont you just use slideToggle()?